# Is it possible to automate shutdown in Azure VMs to save costs?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

I am trying to create a VM from the Azure portal.

I followed this Microsoft Doc to create it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal

I successfully created a VM with Windows Server 2019 image. I have to work in that till 5 pm daily and have to shut down it manually while logging off the work. Is there any way to automatically shut down it if I forget to do that manually in order to save costs whenever it is not in use? Or Is there any template to do that?

If possible, can you help me with the steps on how to do that?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that and for that you need to open your Azure VM, in the left pane under Operations there is an Auto-shutdown option which you can leverage to set a time at which you need to shutdown the VM

There's also a feature to notify users before a shut down so that they can save any unsaved work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Automation Account? Here are the [`steps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management-enable) to configure VM to start/shut down based on hours. or you can set it as [Auto shutdown](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-auto-shutdown-for-vms-using-azure-resource-manager/) on the VM itself.